# Is it possible to define optional arguments within functions in Rust?

Tags: rust

Does Rust allow for optional function arguments, which I can then set to some default value, such as through pattern matching or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically no, but you can piggyback off the `Option` enum which is always available to achieve a similar effect:

```
fn opt_arg(i: Option<int>) {
    match i {
        Some(x) => { println!("Got {}", x); },
        None => { println!("Didn't get anything"); }
    }
}

fn main() {
    opt_arg(None); // Didn't get anything
    opt_arg(Some(2i)); // Got 2
}
```